# Cancelar ou repetir alerta em js

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte js para exibir um alerta.

```
function session_checking1()
{
    $.post( "./alertaposicionamento2", function( data ) {
        if(data.status  == "-1")
        {
           alert('Tem posicionamento em atraso do Utente '+data.value);

        }
    });
}
var validateSession1 = setInterval(session_checking1, 120000);
```

Pretendia que quando exibisse o alerta ao utilizador, o mesmo utilizador tivesse a opção de voltar a receber o mesmo alerta ou cancelar o mesmo alerta, e caso cancelasse o alerta voltasse a ativar ao final de 30 minutos.

Podem ajudar?

Comment: Você pode trabalhar com Sessions e Cookies!

Comment: @Jonathan de Toni pode explicar melhor esse processo para entender melhor? Se possível colocar um exemplo de forma a perceber essa lógica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que trocando o `alert` por `confirm` e `setInterval` por `setTimeout`, conforme código abaixo resolva o seu problema.

```
function session_checking1()
{
    $.post( "./alertaposicionamento2", function( data ) {
        if (data.status == "-1")
        {
           if (confirm('Tem posicionamento em atraso do Utente ' + data.value + ', deseja continuar recebendo alerta?')) {
               setTimeout(session_checking1, 120000);
           } else {
               // disparar requisição ajax que faz (data.status == "-1") retornar false 
               // nas próximas requisições, caso a página seja recarregada
           }
        }
    });
}

setTimeout(session_checking1, 120000);
```

Comment: Sim é isso que pretendo. Só pretendia mais uma coisa, que é,  disser que não quero receber mais este alerta, volta-lo ativar passado meia hora. Assim se o utilizador não cumprir o que o alerta enviou, volta-o a relembrar, mas assim dou um período de tempo para o utilizador resolver o pedido.

Comment: @Junior parece que o seu caso é de somente definir um timeout maior no else do confirm.

Comment: isso mesmo. Obrigado